# HQL Injection/findAll with sorting

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

In my application, the query is being built by appending the first part(where clause) with the second part(order by) using a separate script like QueryBuilder.groovy and hence the order by part is prone to HQL injection which can't be sanitized by using Named Parameters. Therefore, I want to use findAll to retrieve a set of records by passing it a query and sorting and paging parameters separately. I saw an implementation like this:

```
     domainClass.findAll(query,[namedParams],[max: 10, offset: 5])
```

When i passed sortColumn and sortDirection as named parameters, sortColumn worked fine but sortDirection didn't work. i need a way to either make sortDirection work as a named parameter or any other way which will combine 'sorting by direction' with the findAll result. Many people have suggested on various forums to just use the parameters directly as part of the query but it is unacceptable for my application as it will expose the query to HQL Injection.
Thanks in advance.

here is an example:

```
  queryString = "FROM BookCatalog b WHERE b.bookNumber = :bookNumber"
```

this is passed to the QueryBuilder.groovy where something like this happens:

```
  sort = "$params.sortColumn $params.sortDirection"
  queryString.order(sort)

  public void sort(String query){
       this.query = this.query+" order by "+query
  }
```

finally findAll retrieves the list of records:

```
  def list = findAll(queryString,namedParams,queryParams)
```

so as the logic just appends the sorting parameters to the query string a potential hacker can do something like this:

```
  bookCatalogView?offset=2&max=5&sortColumn=1,2,3 **or 1=1**
```

or

```
  bookCatalogView?offset=2&max=5&sortColumn=1,2,3;**select * from whatever**
```

Comment: since the most common way to open yourself to SQL injections is by banging strings together, could you please also add your current code, that can be attacked?

Comment: Using parameterised queries isn't how HQL injection is formed. String concatenation over a *query* is how HQL injection is formed.

Comment: That's the point. Because the logic is concatenating strings, it is prone to injection. Now due to the internal requirement, I cannot have the whole query at a single place. Moreover, 'order by' can't be sanitized by using 'parameterised queries'.

Answer (score 1):

Don't concat strings, it's bad practice.

If you want to create complex queries, consider using createCriteria()

```
SomeDomainClass.createCriteria().list {
    order("propName", "desc")
}
```

or, if you need more control, in the sessionFactory way:

```
query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(DomainClass.class)
query.addOrder(Order.asc("someField"))
query.addOrder(Order.desc("someotherField"))
```